# mysql deadlock in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have several processes running that are updating and deleting rows in one table. Most importantly, these two queries are used:

```
UPDATE `prices_queue` SET `rand` = '$rand' WHERE `rand` = 0 ORDER BY priority DESC, pq_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

(immediately followed by a select to get this row: "SELECT pq_id, asin, shop_id FROM `prices_queue` WHERE `rand` = '$rand')

and

```
DELETE FROM prices_queue WHERE pq_id IN ($idlist) ORDER BY priority DESC, pq_id ASC
```

However, the more of these processes I ran, the more deadlocks I run into.

Information about the latest deadlock:

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
130903  3:38:09
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 8DAF188, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 508 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 133740, OS thread handle 0x41462940, query id 23177920 SERVERNAME init
UPDATE `prices_queue` SET `rand` = '631351' WHERE `rand` = 0  AND shop_id <> 1 ORDER BY priority DESC, pq_id ASC LIMIT 1
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 681 page no 62 n bits 480 index `PRIMARY` of table `prices_queue`         trx id 8DAF188 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 311 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 8003d370; asc    p;;
1: len 6; hex 000008da9806; asc       ;;
2: len 7; hex 290000019703f5; asc )      ;;
3: len 10; hex 30373932323833323532; asc 0792283252;;
4: len 1; hex 07; asc  ;;
5: len 1; hex 32; asc 2;;
6: len 4; hex 000cadd7; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 8DAF187, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 133727, OS thread handle 0x41f33940, query id 23177919 SERVERNAME init
UPDATE `prices_queue` SET `rand` = '844973' WHERE `rand` = 0  ORDER BY priority DESC,     pq_id ASC LIMIT 1
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 681 page no 62 n bits 480 index `PRIMARY` of table     `prices_queue` trx id 8DAF187 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 311 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 8003d370; asc    p;;
1: len 6; hex 000008da9806; asc       ;;
2: len 7; hex 290000019703f5; asc )      ;;
3: len 10; hex 30373932323833323532; asc 0792283252;;
4: len 1; hex 07; asc  ;;
5: len 1; hex 32; asc 2;;
6: len 4; hex 000cadd7; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 681 page no 62 n bits 480 index `PRIMARY` of table `prices_queue`     trx id 8DAF187 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 312 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 7; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 8003d3c4; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000008da99a9; asc       ;;
2: len 7; hex 68000002670ea4; asc h   g  ;;
3: len 10; hex 30303731343538323731; asc 0071458271;;
4: len 1; hex 03; asc  ;;
5: len 1; hex 32; asc 2;;
6: len 4; hex 00002a98; asc   * ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

I understand that these two queries block eachother:

```
UPDATE `prices_queue` SET `rand` = '631351' WHERE `rand` = 0  AND shop_id <> 1 ORDER BY priority DESC, pq_id ASC LIMIT 1

UPDATE `prices_queue` SET `rand` = '844973' WHERE `rand` = 0  ORDER BY priority DESC, pq_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

but why?

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an index on rand?

Comment: yes i do. is that good or bad?

Comment: It is good and actually very important. Try a compound index on rand and priority, just in case. Please give us the output of EXPLAIN of the 2 queries, replacing UPDATE ... SET with SELECT rand